# Laravel system returns NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, compiled, illuminate-container

My laravel 4 projects sometimes prints an error in error logs as following:

```
 exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in /var/www/html/projectname/bootstrap/compiled.php:5336 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/projectname/bootstrap/compiled.php(4685): 
 Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #1 /var/www/html/projectname/bootstrap/compiled.php(4673): 
 Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #2 /var/www/html/projectname/bootstrap/compiled.php(4665): 
 Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #3 /var/www/html/projectname/bootstrap/compiled.php(706): 
 Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #4 /var/www/html/projectname/bootstrap/compiled.php(687):
 Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #5 /var/www/html/projectname/bootstrap/compiled.php(1146): 
 Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true) #6 /var/www/html/projectname/bootstrap/compiled.php(7308): 
 Illuminate\Http\FrameGuard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true) #7 /var/www/html/projectname/bootstrap/compiled.php(7905): 
 Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true) #8 /var/www/html/projectname/bootstrap/compiled.php(7852): 
 Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true) #9 /var/www/html/projectname/bootstrap/compiled.php(10872): 
 Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true) #10 /var/www/html/projectname/bootstrap/compiled.php(648):
 Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #11 /var/www/html/projectname/public/index.php(65): 
 Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run() #12
 {main}
```

I couldn't solve the problem. What is the reason for this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It happens when Laravel can't find a route for the request.

Comment: What is the url that is causing the error and the code e.g. routes, controllers related to it?

Comment: That is the real problem. I can't find it. How can I find the url that causes this error?

Comment: Probably in your access logs for whatever web server you're using (Apache or Ngnix).